# How do you join two tables based on substring matches in Azure Data Explorer / Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I would like to create a resulting table from the joining of these two tables based on the cells in the `Fruit` having substring matches in the `Things` data table.

```
let Fruit = datatable(fruit:string) 
[
"apple", 
"banana" 
"orange" 
];
let Things = datatable(fruit:string) 
[
"anappletree",
"myoranges" 
];
```

I've tried something like this:

```
Fruit
| join Things on $left.fruit contains $right.thing
```

But get this error:

```
Semantic Error 
join: only column entities or equality expressions are allowed in this context.
```

So can't use `contains` here.

How do I join this such that I can get a table consisting of

```
"apple" | "anappletree"
"banana" | ""
"orange" | "myoranges"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the left side of the `join` (in your case - `Fruit`) is small enough, you could try using `mv-apply`:

```
let Fruit = datatable(fruit:string) 
[
    "apple", 
    "banana",
    "orange" 
];
let Things = datatable(thing:string) 
[
    "anappletree",
    "myoranges",
    "this is not a fruit"
];
let Fruit_list = toscalar(Fruit | summarize make_list(fruit));
Things
| mv-apply fruit = Fruit_list on (where thing contains fruit)
```

| thing | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| anappletree | apple |
| myoranges | orange |

---

Alternatively, as `join` only supports equality as of this writing, you can try using a cross-join, then filtering using `contains`:

```
let Fruit = datatable(fruit:string) 
[
    "apple", 
    "banana",
    "orange" 
];
let Things = datatable(thing:string) 
[
    "anappletree",
    "myoranges",
    "this is not a fruit"
];
Fruit
| extend dummy = 1
| join kind=inner (Things | extend dummy = 1) on dummy
| where thing contains fruit
| project-away dummy*
```

| fruit | thing |
| --- | --- |
| apple | anappletree |
| orange | myoranges |